# How To Add A Custom Field To Moodle Language Email String (newusernewpasswordtext)

Tags: php, moodle

I created some custom field (title) in my Moodle install: I need to include it in the customization of the Moodle Language String (newusernewpasswordtext).

**The default language string is:**

Hi {$a->firstname}, A new account has been created for you at '{$a->sitename}' and you have been...

I need to update it to allow updating with the custom field, 'title' and a default field of last name.

**I added the following string:**

Hi {$a->profile_field_title} {$a->firstname} {$a->lastname}, A new account has been created for you at '{$a->sitename}' and you have been...

**Output:**

Hi {$a->profile_field_title} John Doe {$a->lastname}, A new account has been created for you at 'www.mysite.com' and you have been...

How can I insert a custom field in the string?

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do that without editing Moodle core code. The `newusernewpassword` email is generated and sent in the *lib/moodlelib.php* file with the `setnew_password_and_mail` function. You'll need to change the object that's passed into that string to include your profile field before you can edit the language pack:

```
$yourfieldid = $DB->get_field('user_info_field', 'id', array('name'=>'profile_field_title'));

$a = new stdClass();
$a->firstname = fullname($user, true);
...
$a->your_profile_field = $DB->get_field('user_info_data', 'data', 
                              array('userid'=>$user->id, 'fieldid'=>$yourfieldid));
```

Then you would change your string to:

> Hi {$a->your_profile_field} {$a->firstname}, A new account has been
>   created for you at '{$a->sitename}' and you have been...

Also note: the reason {$a->lastname} shows up in your output as well is because the object that's passed into the function that makes the email doesn't have a 'lastname'-- the last name is included in the 'firstname' through Moodle's fullname function.

Answer (score 0):

By going to Home Site administration> Users> Permissions> User policies, you can change the fullname function of Moodle. Change both Set both 'Full name format' and 'Alternative full name format' from the default language to the desired format (firstname, lastname, etc.)